# Hove the menu will move the other menus

Tags: html, css

```
#menu-main-menu li a{padding: 13px 15px 2px 15px;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 30px;
}

#menu-main-menu li a:hover{

background: white;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
border-bottom:none;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;}
```

this is my code of my site [ http://96.30.0.16/~loansdir/] please help me for my problem, if I will hove the menu, some menus will move can you please help me with this isue? thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you're adding borders on hover. You have to add the equivalent amount of space in the normal state, or you'll see a little jitter. If I'm reading your CSS correctly that means you need to add 1px extra space on the top, left, and right edges. How about:

```
#menu-main-menu li a {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    ...
}
#menu-main-menu li a:hover {
    border-color: #CDCDCD;
    ...
}
```

That should set up a transparent border on the top/left/right, remove the bottom border for all states, and just change the border color on hover.

Answer (score 1):

The border on the hover is causing the li to grow - thus pushing the li's after it to the left.

To get around this you could:

- Instead of applying the border on the `<a>` element itself - you could use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element :after the `<a>` to acheive this effect. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9SXcH/4/)**
- Give your li's a fixed width - say 53px. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9SXcH/3/)**
- <strike>Use `outline` instead of `border`</strike>
  (I don't think there is a cross-browser way to give outline rounded corners)